# Generalized Unitarity cut of Scalar One-loop Box integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, supersymmetry, unitarity

How does one perform the integrals in four particle cuts in generalized unitarity? It would be helpful how one finds solutions to the simplest case, the fully determined box integral given by:

$\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^4k}{(2 \pi)^4} \delta(k^2) \delta((k+p1)^2)\delta((k+p1+p2)^2)\delta((k+p1+p2+p3)^2)$

Where the k and $p_i$ are 4-dimensional complex momenta, and the external $p_i$ are massless and on shell i.e., $p_i^2=0$. I know there exist two solutions to the problem, and it would be helpful to be expressed in terms of mandelstam variables s,t,u

I'm sure you can take a jacobian of each delta argument expanded explicitly in terms of (k0,k1,...) but I feel there should be an easier solution

Comment: If you want the result for the scalar one-loop box diagram, you have it [here](http://qcdloop.fnal.gov/boxdiv1.pdf) (with references at the end of the page), on this nice [site](http://qcdloop.fnal.gov/). However, I don't think on-shell techniques change the answer. Maybe this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697v1.pdf), Chapter $8$, page $120$, or this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5605v1.pdf), pages $17,18$, pages $126,127$ might interest you.